# System settings not launching on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-settings, gnome-control-center

From the drop-down menu, top right corner, I have access only to the volume, brightness control, and power on or off buttons.

None of the other icons launch, including Account Settings, Wifi control, wired connection, and the control center.

Output of `apt policy gnome-control-center`:

```
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
Version table:
   1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
      500 ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
   1:3.28.1-0ubuntu1 500
      500 ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What is the output of the following command in Terminal: `apt policy gnome-control-center`?

Comment: this what I get, every thing worked fine last week  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Version table:
     1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.28.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages